# Invalid default timestamp with timezone value for a column in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a table with the following structure:

```
   Column   |           Type           |  Default
------------+--------------------------+---------
 start_time | timestamp with time zone |
 end_time   | timestamp with time zone |
 created_at | timestamp with time zone | timezone('UTC'::text, now())
```

plus some *additional fields*.

I `insert` data into the table likewise (in Java, using JDBC):

```
// INSERT statement
// INSERT INTO table (start_time, end_time) VALUES (?::timestamptz, ?::timestamptz);

// statement => PreparedStatement
// sample.start(), sample.end() => java.time.LocalDateTime
statement.setString(START_IDX, sample.start().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
statement.setString(END_IDX, sample.end().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));
```

*Acceptable* difference between `end_time` and `created_at` should be a few seconds.

But now when I query the data in `psql`

```
-- LIMIT, ORDER BY removed for brevity
SELECT created_at, start_time, end_time FROM table
```

I get the result

```
    created_at             |    start_time             |    end_time    
---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------
 2018-09-27 09:13:07+05:30 | 2018-09-27 14:42:00+05:30 | 2018-09-27 14:43:00+05:30
```

**There shouldn't be a `+05:30` at the end of `created_at`!!!**
I guess that means that Postgres is treating the timestamp *with timezone* as `09:13:07` at `IST` where it should treat it as `09:13:07` at `UTC`!!

And that breaks a bunch of stuff further down the road!

So, my question is, what is causing this issue? is it a bug (1%)? or am I missing something on my side (99%)?

P.S. I am on Windows 10 64-bit and using Postgres 10.3

#### EDIT(1):

The table is created as

```
CREATE TABLE behaviour_sample (
  sample        JSON NOT NULL,
  start_time    TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
  end_time      TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
  device        CHAR(16) REFERENCES device(eui) NOT NULL,
  created_at    TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
);
```

#### Edit(2):

Ok, so I checked my other tables and they too have a similar issue!

The one thing all of them have in common is that the `created_at` field is *created* using

```
created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
```

so if I create a record at, say, `14:30:00 +05:30` it shows `09:00:00 +05:30` when queried! the time at `utc` but with time zone `ist` (the `+05:30` part)

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) "*For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value **is always in UTC***" and "*When a timestamp with time zone value is output, it is always **converted from UTC to the current timezone zone**, and displayed as local time in that zone*".

Comment: ah.. yea! but the local time when the record is created is `14:43:07 +05:30`, so shouldn't  it display that??

Comment: No. It's the local time of the **client** at the time when the data is queried. A `timestamptz` does not store the "original time zone"

Comment: ok... so does that mean Postgres is storing `09:13:07` (`UTC` when the _client's_ local time is `14:43:07 +05:30`)?? If so, then when I query it back _shouldn't_ it _convert_ `09:13:07` back to `14:43:07` (given _client's_ time zone is `+05:30`)??

Comment: and thus the output should be `2018-09-27 14:43:07+05:30` and _not_ `2018-09-27 09:13:07+05:30`